# How to import similarity matrix in Gephi

Tags: matrix, graph, similarity, gephi

I have stored o matrix of similarity in csv file which contains values of probabilities between 0 and 1 and I want to know if there is a way to import this matrix into Gephi to visualize the graph with different colors

Answer (score 0):

I don't import networks like this generally but I tried the following steps:

1. Created a random graph in Gephi
2. Exported as CSV
3. Reimported in Gephi (**File>Open** and just opened the previously generated CSV)

For a graph with 50 nodes the CSV was 51 x 51 taking into account that first row/column has node ids. The entries of the CSV are the edge weights of course.

Here is what it looks like:

```
;0;1;2;...;49
0;0;0;...;0
1;0;0;...;1.0
```

Check the entire file here: http://pastebin.com/NsbwCsZQ

**NB:** The file is actually semi-colon separated. I 'm not entirely sure why but I am running Gephi in Windows so it might have to do with it